# Dollar bars in Advances in Financial Machine Learning book

Tags: algorithmic-trading, machine-learning

Does anyone have use the dollar bars for building a strategy? I would like to know what ways you guys might be interested to set the dollar bars' parameter ( the dollar value ). I have thought of one way is to take the EMA of the past 20 days' daily dollar value but that seems not robust enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the literature in the references and bibliography sections you will see that a common technique is to sample about 50 times a day. This is done by calculating the 30 day moving average of volume and then dividing by 50.

This will give you the threshold level needed for sampling on a volume clock.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Joubert.